# diff B..A shows four additions; rebase B onto A shows 2 changes and 50 unmerged paths

Tags: git

HEAD is current at `branchB` and we would like to rebase onto `branchA`.

```
* 4e4dd23 (HEAD, branchB) 
| * 0b50615 (branchA)
|/
* dbca6fd (branchC)
| * 9b08e2e (branchOther) 
|/
* f3db5ee (master) 
* 4d03982 
* 9d332c0 
* 2aa39e0
```

Running a `git diff branchA.. --name-status` shows this output:

```
A       newFile1
A       newFile2
A       newFile3
A       newFile4
```

We expected `git rebase branchA` therefor to run smoothly. It doesn't. Rather, just after the rebase starts, `git status` outputs this:

```
rebase in progress; onto 0b50615
You are currently rebasing branch 'branchB' on '0b50615'.

Changes to be committed:

        new file:   newFile1
        new file:   newFile2

Unmerged paths:

        added by us:     someFile1
        added by us:     someFile2
        added by us:     someFile3
        added by us:     someFile...
        added by us:     someFile50
```

Questions:

1. Why are there only two changes to be committed? We expected four, one for each new file.
2. Why are there unmerged paths? We expected none because the `diff` showed only additions.

Answer (score -1):

It turns out that `git rebase` does not care about `git diff`. Rather, it cares about `git log`.

> All changes made by commits in the current branch but that are not in  are saved to a temporary area. This is the same set of commits that would be shown by `git log <upstream>..HEAD`.

https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase

Oddly, the fix was the following:

```
git add -A
git commit -m "(WAT?) Add missing files"
git rebase continue
```

At this point, git rejected the `continue` and recommended `skip`.

```
git rebase --skip
```

Done. Odd.

Also, we lost two files in the process. A `git diff` against the relevant `reflog` item found them.

**Note**: This is a partial answer/workaround. More help would be great.

Comment: More precisely, `git rebase` *copies* commits.  This means it cares about commits.  Meanwhile, `git diff` typically compares two commits—which seems like maybe the same thing, except the question now becomes: *which* two commits? Using `git log` you will see commits in some order; with luck you may even see them in the *right* order. Rebase uses the equivalent of `git log --topo-order --reverse --no-merges` by default.